# In Ruby on Rails, why is "bundle install" so slow to create Gemfile.lock and "rails g foo name:string" creates it so quickly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundle

I already have all the gems, and each time I do

```
rails trytry02
cd trytry02
bundle install
```

to create the Gemfile.lock, it takes a long time to fetch data from rubygems.org.  But I noticed that if I do a

```
rails g scaffold foo name:string
```

before doing the bundle install, then the Gemfile.lock is created very fast.  Is there a way to create it fast but not using `rails g scaffold`?

Comment: Is this not because by the time you do the bundle install the second time all the required gems are cached locally?

Answer (score 12):

Douglas is correct, this is because `bundle install` is doing a round trip to `rubygems.org` to look for newer versions.  If you want to just use the local versions...

```
bundle install --local
```

**But** - why are you generating your `Gemfile.lock` so often that this is an issue?  Your `Gemfile.lock` should be under version control, ie. part of your project, and so should only change occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change https to http in the Gemfile and see if this increases its speed.